# Disqus comments and pingback script - how to change the order?

Tags: comments, disqus, pingbacks

I am using the "[modular demo solution without wp_list_comments()](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/124473/how-to-show-disqus-comments-and-pingbacks)" for showing trackbacks and pingbacks next to Disqus comments.

And I would like to know how to change the order of output? With these script, the trackbacks/pingbacks are placed above the comments. I would like to place them below the comments.

Can anybody help me with that?

Best regards

Manuel

Answer (score 1):

oh, it looks like I wrote that script, so let me try to answer you ;-)

You could for example:

- add your own action hook in your template,
- use javascript to move the pings below the *Disqus* comments,
- hijack the `disqus_language_filter` filter of the *Disqus* plugin.

If you go for the last option, you could use this modification of the `PingsList` class instead:

```
/**
 * Modified version of PingsList to display the pings below the Disqus comments.
 * @see http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/174468/26350
 */

class PingsList
{
    protected $pd;
    protected $pw;

    public function __construct( IPingsView $pw, IPingsData $pd )
    {
        $this->pw = $pw;
        $this->pd = $pd;
    }
    public function init()
    {
        $this->pd->init();
        add_filter( 'disqus_language_filter', array( $this, 'disqus_language_filter' ) );
    }

    public function disqus_language_filter( $lang )
    {
        $this->pw->template( $this->pd->get_data() );
        return $lang;
    }

} // end class
```

This should display the pings below the *Disqus* comments.

Comment: Hi birgire, thanks for your help. Unfortunately, the change of that value does not change the order. Pingbacks are still above the comments. I have checked values from 1 up to 200. No difference.

Comment: @marowi Please check the updated answer.